# What is the best way to examine minified javascript file in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio

Many times I have been in a situation to be given minified javascript and css files just to use them in html. For equivalent situation in .Net, I simply use Object Browser in Visual Studio where I can see all methods and properties with comments which makes it very clear for using given dll with classes. Is there some equivalent tool/method to examine minified javascript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use something like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or the Chrome Dev tools have a {} button when you are in source view to format the js. I dont think there is any built in feature in VS to do this. There *might* be a plug in but a quick search didn't turn anything up except for Visual Studio 2010 there was a plugin called PrettyJS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this two extensions [Web Extensions Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack) and [Web Essentials](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebEssentials20153) for Visual Studio for web projects. They add a lot of useful functions for web. For example, Un-minify  document which does the same as the http://jsbeatifier.org/ does.